# How can I get the standard deviation for a set of rows in my dataframe based on a condition in one column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of

```
years, latitude, longitude
1971, 30.212, -87.423
1971, 30.211, -87.455
1971, 30.111, -94.444
1972, 24.114, -94.231
1972, 25.114, -92.121
```

I want to find the standard distribution for the latitude column by year, such that a new column is created, and would have a repeating standard distribution for each instance of 1971, and a different sd for 1972, etc.

I believe this may be somewhere in the dplyr universe? having difficulties with this one.

In a logical experession, I am asking: what is the standard deviation for `df$latitude`, WHEN `df$years` = "all Patterns (being years)"

Comment: `df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(lat_sd = sd(lat))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, using base R...

```
df$lat_sd <- ave(df$lat, df$year, FUN=sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(lat_sd=sd(latitutde, na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is built like this and is stored in a variable called "df":

```
year, lat, long
1971, 20, 40
```

You would need this code using dplyr:

```
output <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(dev = sd(lat))

merge(df, output, by = "year")
```